# Why does this produce "missing \endcsname" error?

Tags: errors, debugging, xstring, csname

I need to dynamically create the name of a macro, where part of the name is based on the argument which needs to be capitalized beforehand. The following MWE illustrates my intention:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\CommandOne}{bla}
\newcommand{\CommandTwo}{more bla}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{
  \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\strHead]%
  \StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}[\strTail]%
  \csname Command\MakeUppercase{\strHead}\strTail\endcsname%
}

\begin{document}

\foo{one}
\foo{two}

\end{document}
```

However, this produces

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
```

upon compilation. Why, and how do I fix it?

Comment: That's because `\MakeUppercase` isn't expandable, I guess. You could try `\tl_upper_case:n` from `expl3` (I haven't tested your MWE and my suggestion though).

Comment: @yudai-nkt: Yes, that should work

Comment: the above comments show what you should do, the reason for the error is that the xstring  commands are as if you had gone `\csname\def\tmp{ZZZ}\tmp\endcsname` which does not work, you can not do definitions inside csname, you need `\def\tmp{ZZZ}\csname\tmp\endcsname`